# Java LongStream to sum int array elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Because many integers can overflow when summed, I needed a long stream to do the job but it wont accept `int` array. How can I convert each element at the time of streaming instead of using a `long` array?

```
// arr is an int[]
LongStream s = Arrays.stream( arr); // error
result = s.reduce(0, Long::sum);
```

Edit: it appears that integer stream is turned into a long one using its method as in Tagir Valeev's answer.

> LongStream asLongStream();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`IntStream.asLongStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asLongStream--) method:

```
LongStream s = Arrays.stream(arr).asLongStream();
```

By the way `s.reduce(0, Long::sum)` is the longer alternative for simple [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum--) method (which internally does the same):

```
long result = Arrays.stream(arr).asLongStream().sum();
```

Comment: This doesnt copy array to a temporary long array I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, Of course it does not copy.

Comment: When I use parallel version, it calculates at 5ms at first(16M elements), then at seconds later, each sum taking 15ms suddenly. Is this a consequence of some garbage collection?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, parallel calculation and benchmarking is probably a complete different story. Post the separate question with complete time measurement code and all your numbers (elements count, times, etc.). In general if you worry about efficiency, simple for-loop here probably would outperform the stream API even in parallel as summation is very simple operation.

Comment: Use jmh to set up a proper benchmark environment for your code. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Thank you. Will look into that.